# Can I set a serial number for each columns or row in a sequential manner?

Tags: views, 8

Can I set a serial number for each column or row, in a sequential manner, from left to right, without doing it manually?

I am using *Content* format, not *Field*. There is no option to add a result counter field.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When format is content

You can override `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` and perhaps create a twig file for just this particular view.

If your view name is **test** you can copy from `core/modules/views/templates/views-view-unformatted.html.twig` to your `THEMENAME/templates` folder and rename to `views-view-unformatted--test.html.twig`.  In this twig file you can use `{{loop.index}}` inside the for loop to give you the row index/count sort of like this:

```
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    <span>row count: {{loop.index}}</span>    
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

### When format is fields

Yes you can add *view results counter* when the format is *fields*

*[image: fields]*

Answer (score 0):

> Can we give serial numbers in views to each columns or row in a
>   sequential manner?

In FIELDS, Add, **Views result counter**.

> How to could i get row counter value in views twig template?

Assuming you're using **views-view-fields--[viewname].html.twig** you can print it with

`{{ fields.counter.content }}`